# ajax code to post a data to a php page and get result as json encode as multidimensional array for individual item?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

Sorry for the weird question title.

Here what I am trying to say is that - I have two tables in my DB. table1 is hotel table and table2 is roomtype table and what I am trying to do is when a customer customize his travel package he should be able to change the hotel as per different location using single modal.

my problem: when I am passing the location in a PHP page (i.e hotel_selector.php) I should get a JSON as

```
[
    {
        "hotel_id": "1",
        "hotel_name": "velocity",
        "hotel_location": "portblair",
        "hotel_type": "3",
        "hotel_img": "velocity.jpg",
        "roomtype_id": "1",
        "type_name": "Deluxe",
        "type_description": "blah",
        "type_img": "deluxe.jpg"
    },
    {
        "hotel_id": "2",
        "hotel_name": "whitecoral",
        "hotel_location": "portblair",
        "hotel_type": "3",
        "hotel_img": "white_coral.jpg",
        "roomtype_id": "1",
        "type_name": "luxury",
        "type_description": "blah",
        "type_img": "luxury.jpg"
    }
]
```

but i have more than one roomtype for single hotel, so how can i show hotels with roomtypes when user clicks on change hotel button.

my php code (hotel_selector.php)

```html
<?php
if(isset($_POST['location'])){
$location = $_POST['location'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
include 'mysql.php';
$result = array();
$result2 = array();
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hotel WHERE hotel_location = '$location' AND visibility = 'visible'")or die("the query cannot be completed");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
 $hotel_id = $row['hotel_id']; 
 $sql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM room_type WHERE hotel_id = '$hotel_id'");
 while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($sql, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
  
 $result2[] = $row1; 
 }
 
$result[] = $row;                   
                  
}
echo json_encode($result); 
echo json_encode($result2); 

}

?>
```

my Ajax code:

```js
<script>
function hotel_selector(id,location,date){
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 var sector = id;
 var place = location;
 $("#hotel_in").html(place);
 $("#hotel_on").html(date);
 var sel_rooms = $("#rooms_"+id).val();
 
 var data21,data22; 
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "hotel_selector.php",
        data: {location:place},
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function(i, item){
               data21 = item.data21;
               data22 = item.data22;
            });
            alert(data21,data22);
        }
    });
 /*$.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url:'hotel_selector.php',
        data: 'location='+ place +'&date='+date,                 
        success: function(value){
   var data = JSON.parse(value);
   data.forEach(function(type){
     var hotel_id =  type.hotel.hotel_id;
     var hotel_name =  type.hotel.hotel_name;
     var hotel_location =  type.hotel.hotel_location;
     var hotel_type =  type.hotel.hotel_type;
     var tripadvisor =  type.hotel.hotel_description;
     var hotel_img =  type.hotel.hotel_img;
     var roomtype_id =  type.roomtype.roomtype_id;
     var type_name =  type.roomtype.type_name;
     var type_description =  type.roomtype.description;
     var type_img =  type.roomtype.img;
     alert("hotel_id:"+hotel_id+"roomtype_id:"+roomtype_id+" type_name:"+type_name+" Selected Rooms:"+sel_rooms);
   });
  }
    });*/
});
}
</script>
```

my older approach without ajax. jst using php for diffrent location modal:

[image: i want a common modal for all places]

any help would be appreciated. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try json_encode both return arrays in one object:

```
hotel_selector.php:

...
echo json_encode(array("hotels" => $result, "rooms" => $result2));
```

And have in your ajax call something like this:

```
...
success: function (data) {
     alert("hotels: " + data.hotels + "\nrooms: " + data.rooms);
}
```

Comment: iam getting alert value as- hotels: undefined rooms: undefined

Comment: Undefined probably means you refer to the wrong array key in your alert. Try display your entire return json object with `alert(JSON.stringify(data))`in the success function

Answer (score 0):

How about *merging*? Have a look at these 2 arrays :

```
<?php
$one = array(
"hotel_id" => "1",
"roomtype_id" =>"1"
);

$two = array(
"hotel_id" => "2",
"roomtype_id" =>"1"
);


$three[0] = array_merge($one,$two);
$three[1] = array_merge($one,$two);
echo( json_encode($three));
?>
```

They will get printed as :

```
[
   {
      "hotel_id":"1",
      "roomtype_id":"1"
   },
   {
     "hotel_id":"2",
     "roomtype_id":"1"
   }
]
```

My idea is that you can merge *$result* & *$result2* on each iteration, and put the merged array as an *element* of a new associative array :

```
$result = array();
$result2 = array();
$merged_array = array();

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hotel WHERE hotel_location = '$location' AND visibility = 'visible'")or die("the query cannot be completed");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    $hotel_id = $row['hotel_id'];   
    $sql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM room_type WHERE hotel_id = '$hotel_id'");
    while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($sql, MYSQL_ASSOC)){

    $result2[] = $row1; 
    }   
$result[] = $row;                                             

$merged_array [] =  array_merge($result1,$result2); // see here .....

}
/*echo json_encode($result); 
echo json_encode($result2); 
*/

echo  json_encode($merged_array);// see here........
```

Comment: iam getting same hotels multiple times

Comment: my output is like this:

Comment: [[{"hotel_id":"1","hotel_name":"velocity","hotel_location":"portblair","hotel_type":"2","hotel_description":"","hotel_img":"velocity.jpg","visibility":"visible"},{"roomtype_id":"1","hotel_id":"1","type_name":"Deluxe","description":"","img":"3.jpg"},{"roomtype_id":"4","hotel_id":"1","type_name":"Luxury","description":"","img":"3.jpg"},{"roomtype_id":"9","hotel_id":"1","type_name":"Super Luxury","description":"","img":"3.jpg"},{"roomtype_id":"10","hotel_id":"1","type_name":"Ultra Luxury","description":"","img":""},{"roomtype_id":"11","hotel_id":"1","type_name":"test","description":"","img":""}],

Comment: [{"hotel_id":"1","hotel_name":"velocity","hotel_location":"portblair","hotel_type":"2","hotel_description":"","hotel_img":"velocity.jpg","visibility":"visible"},{"hotel_id":"3","hotel_name":"White Coral","hotel_location":"portblair","hotel_type":"3","hotel_description":"","hotel_img":"White Coral.jpg","visibility":"visible"},{"roomtype_id":"1","hotel_id":"1","type_name":"Deluxe","description":"","img":"3.jpg"},{"roomtype_id":"4","hotel_id":"1","type_name":"Luxury","description":"","img":"3.jpg"},{"roomtype_id":"9","hotel_id":"1","type_name":"Super Luxury","description":"","img":"3.jpg"},

Comment: {"roomtype_id":"10","hotel_id":"1","type_name":"Ultra Luxury","description":"yts h h h xnh hs ns","img":"3.jpg"},{"roomtype_id":"11","hotel_id":"1","type_name":"test","description":"dddddd","img":"test.jpg"},{"roomtype_id":"2","hotel_id":"3","type_name":"Std Ac","description":"","img":""},{"roomtype_id":"5","hotel_id":"3","type_name":"lux","description":"","img":""}]]

Comment: the above three comments are my output when i use ajax:             success: function(value){ $("#hotel_details").html(value); }